# Which of the function words will be stressed?

Tags: articles, pronouns, conjunctions, word-stress

> **Me**, and thousands of others in this country like me, are half baked **because** we were never allowed to complete **our** schooling. Open our skulls, look in with a pen light and you'll find **an** old museum of ideas.

I am putting stress over the words that I want the listner to be attentive towards. Is this approach correct? How to find out which functional words should we put stress upon?

Comment: To start with, the subject of the sentence should be **I** and not **me**. If this is intended to be spoken, it would sound very odd if the speaker stressed only the words in bold.

Comment: Not just the words in bold will be stressed as I have only mentioned the function words that will be stressed and not the content words.

Comment: @KateBunting (On "I" and "me") Yes, but the sentence itself says that the author is uneducated (or under-educated, at least). At any rate, it isn't a sentence that the OP has come up with but rather a quote from Aravind Adiga's novel *The White Tiger*.